# The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value error

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I made iPhone app, now i want to upload this app in Appstore.

When i try to upload archive file from organizer it shows me this error:

[image]:
`Bundle identifier` in my target project is `com.Appname`

What changes i need to do ?

**Please help and thanks in advance.**

Comment: Using which identifier you have set up in `itunesConnect`? is app is created with same identifier?

Comment: how you have created app in itunesConnect? app desc, screenshts,etc.

Comment: Manage your apps- Addnewapp- filled all details, http://i.imgur.com/NMnFEkJ.png

Comment: and what identifier use in xcode for creating acrhive?

Comment: here it is, http://i.imgur.com/OFGVyGF.png

Comment: is it proper ? or i am doing mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it shows that both identifiers are not same,

- Create new identifier like, **`com.cmpny.appname`**
- Set up again itunes app using this identifier
- Use this identifier in xcode  and create archive

Comment: where should i create new identifier in Xcode or in itunesconnect ?

Comment: you have to create new budleidentifier in developer portal, `developer.apple.com`

Comment: and use this in , new certificates, xcode, and at itunes.

Answer (score 3):

So here's what's happening:

1. You have previously registered an app ID in iTunes connect which is "waiting for upload," and you've forgotten about it.
2. You have just made another app which you are trying to validate, but the status in iTunes connect is "prepare for upload."
3. When you hit "validate", the Organizer shows the old App name as the Application name, where it says "Application:" which you are probably overlooking.

And here's what you need to do:

1. Go to iTunes connect and change your NEW app's status from prepare to upload, to waiting for upload, by hitting the blue button "ready to upload binary" on the top right corner of the screen.
2. Go back to the Organizer window and hit "validate." Xcode will now recognize the new app and you won't get the error message you reported above.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your bundle identifier should be com.companyname.appname

Set this identifier in Xcode project settings.

Create App id using this Bundle ID in iTunes connect.

Create a provisioning profile using the new app id. 
Take a new ipa file using this profile. and try validation.

Make sure that the bundle identifier used in your xcode project target settings and the bundle identifier in app details in iTunes connect should be same.

Note: Please create new app in iTunes with the new bundle identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Go to iTunes Connect -> Menu More -> About this app and change the Bundle ID and bundle ID Suffix.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the lowercase / uppercase bundle ID which was set in the app and in iTunes. Make sure they are the same - change the iTunes one from More->About this app