# ERROR-ITMS-9000: Bundle identifier cannot be changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: "The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value,    if you want to change your bundle identifier, you will need to create      a new application in iTunes Connect.  "at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset    (MzItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
```

I have tried recreating the provisioning profile, checked the appid matches in all areas - restarted machine, deleted and re-added tags - always get the same error?

Comment: Have you checked bundleId for its case sensitivity in app's code, iTunes connect, and your developer account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your itunesconnect bundle identifier and your app bundle identifier it should be same.because you are getting error due to your bundle identifier is mismatch with your itunesconnect bundle identifers. you can check also following link this is also suffering with your problem
[The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473347/the-bundle-identifier-cannot-be-changed-from-the-current-value-error)